# How to check if the array of objects contains same value for a specific key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I have the following array of objects:

```
const array = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "environment":"ENV1",
        "other_key":"other_value"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "environment":"ENV1",
        "other_key":"other_value_two"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "environment":"ENV2",
        "other_key":"other_value_three"
    }
]
```

Now I need to show an alert if the array has diifferent values for environment. If all environments are same, I don't need to show the alert. In the above example, I need to show the warning alert.

How can I check if the array contains different values for a specific key or it has the same value ?

Comment: you can filter your array

Comment: Can you please show an example ?

Comment: var filter=array.filter(i=>i.environment==="ENV2");
console.log(filter.length?"has env 2":"all good")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could do this:

```js
const array = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "environment":"ENV1",
        "other_key":"other_value"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "environment":"ENV1",
        "other_key":"other_value_two"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "environment":"ENV2",
        "other_key":"other_value_three"
    }
]

const everyEnvHasSameValue = array.every( ({other_key}) => other_key === array[0].other_key); // use proper name

console.log(everyEnvHasSameValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just use filter here:

```
const array = [
    {
        "id":1,
        "environment":"ENV1",
        "other_key":"other_value"
    },
    {
        "id":2,
        "environment":"ENV1",
        "other_key":"other_value_two"
    },
    {
        "id":3,
        "environment":"ENV1",
        "other_key":"other_value_three"
    }
]

const el = array.filter(e => e.environment !== array[0].environment)
if(el.length > 0) alert('envs are diff')
```

Comment: But he wanted to compare if `other_key` is having some other value in each item of the array. Also I think it is more suitable to use `every` here since totally suits the use case instead of filtering and then checking for the `length` of the returned array

Comment: How come? He wrote `Now I need to show an alert if the array has diifferent values for environment. If all environments are same, I don't need to show the alert.`. I think he want to check if every object in the array has same value for `environment` property.